# How did events lead this way?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, dexter

In an arguably poor-received way, Dexter ended in a very odd way. Our favourite serial killer is now a lumberjack in wintery... wherever. The question comes back to *why*? Why does Dexter choose to seclude himself in such a fashion when everything was bumpy, but working out well enough?

Comment: Lol at "He can't bare it anymore" by Ankit. He's killed about 100 people, he's not normal. The final season and all of those emotions of Dexter just don't make sense for a psychopath. I wish Vogel could have proven him, that he, in fact, was deluding himself about having feelings for sister and having feelings at all. That would have made so much more sense. How did events lead this way? Poor writing, I am afraid, is the answer.

Comment: @evening Vogel  thinks that psychopaths doesn't have feelings. But Dexter has shown feelings various time for his son Harrison, deb, Hannah and Rita too. Rita's death, Vogel   death, harry's death reason, all made him realize that he is a destroyer. I don't think psychopaths can't have emotions. And more then 100 people he killed are not his relatives but Rita is his wife, Vogel   a mother figure and harry is his dad.

Answer (score 11):

Because Dexter now realizes that he is the one who is responsible for Harry's suicide, Deb's condition of being on life support, Rita's death, and Vogel's death. He can't bare it anymore. He now thinks that everyone he is comes into contact with will be destroyed the same way — that's why after killing The Brain Surgeon he stopped Deb's life support system to free her from anymore pain and even decided to commit suicide too, leaving Harrison in the care of Hannah McKay.

Somehow, he survives and shows up as a lumberjack. This means he survived, but still didn't want to go to Hannah or Harrison in order to save them from his darkness.

The last sight of Dexter eyes were still very arguable making a point for an open end.

Comment: i beg to differ on the somehow he survived, I am sure it was a planned escape.

Comment: @war_Hero that will be pure speculation from both of our sides because we don't have canon answer.

Comment: actually in the book dexter tells this story when he is about to be fried so only the first season was according to book. They have promised a spin off hope it resolves our issue

Comment: @war_Hero after that 8th season i am surely avoiding any sequel, prequel and spin-off from the series. I am still imagining in my head that in season 7 end Deb killed Dexter.

Comment: Isn't Dexter likely to kill again? Like he isn't dead and his 'Dark Passenger' cannot go away just because he feels guilty that everyone he comes in contact with had a bad ending.

Answer (score 2):

If you followed dexter carefully then you will understand the true meaning of the ending.

> **Dexter Always wanted to feel normal**

- Dexter always talks about getting rid of his "Dark Passenger" and hoping to feel normal, Remember In season 4 ending when he is looking into the blood moon and hopes for a normal life.

> **He kills Debra because he loves her**

- In season 2 when the the records keeper is about to die of lung cancer deb says "if that happens to me dex put me out of my misery" and promises she will do the same as dex is family, and only after this conversation dex spikes the pie and kills the record keeper[upon her request as they cant commit suicide as they are catholics].

> **Dexter didn't Abandon his son**

- unlike dexter Hanah didn't have an mental condition to kill people, she just did it to survive and protect, dexter as not shown an alternative by harry and he developed those urges, but little harrison is given an alternative. Also dex didnt want harrison to know he was a serial killer remember the episode where he kills the tooth fairy.

> **Why the lumberjack profession**

- it's the next best alternative to trash something if you are a retired serial killer.

  **All in all i would say this might not be the ending we wanted but its the ending dexter required**

Answer (score 1):

Dexter does deeply care for Debra. She ends up paying for everything evil Dexter does. Rita has already paid with her life because Dexter gets entangled with the Trinity Killer. He originally plans on running away from everything and start his life new with Hannah or Harrison. Before he could execute his plan, Debra ends up in a Coma for life.

Dexter trusts that Hannah will take care of Harrison and his kid's future is in safe custody. The two of them - Hannah and Harrison will go away to a new place and start life new.

Dexter realizes that if he joins Hannah and Harrison he will only be putting the two of them in danger like he put Rita and Debra. If he stays alive in the eyes of the world, they will constantly try and reach out to him. He plans to fake his death. Drives off his boat into a storm, I suppose he jumped out before getting caught in the storm and got to shore somehow.

Now to the world he's dead. He can live in isolation and not endanger anybody but himself.

Why lumberjack? Well, it's just a profession that doesn't need a college degree and can be picked up based on his physical strength. This way no one gets to know that he was once a blood spatter expert and worked for the police department. The idea is that he has completely given up his previous career and the people in his life to stay as a loner.